# Aggregate rows by group_by conditional

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to solve this in dplyr if possible.

I have a data frame:

```
Item         Count
Bike Tire    15
Car Tire     6
H. Window    3
S. Windows   7
Spare Tires  1
Widget X     88
Widget Z     34
...
```

I want to get the data frame to aggregate to:

```
Item       Count
Tires      22
H. Window  3
S. Windows 7 
Widget X   88
Widget Z   34
...
```

I got this far `filter(data, grepl(glob2rx("*tire*"), data$Item, ignore.case = TRUE)` so that I could see what rows would match, but how can I `group_by` so I can then aggregate the data in the example? I will also probably do the same for the other items but just want to understand the base case first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option to `replace` the 'Item' having 'tire' substring with 'Tires' in the `group_by` and get the `sum` of 'Count'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Item = replace(Item, grepl("Tire", Item), "Tires")) %>%
   summarise(Count = sum(Count))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Item       Count
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 H. Window      3
#2 S. Windows     7
#3 Tires         22
#4 Widget X      88
#5 Widget Z      34
```

Comment: Do you mean tires?

Comment: @Shawn Sorry, it is Tires.  Updated

Comment: So ultimately the replace happens first and at this point the group_by is really only an explicit group by=Item. You could have also done the replace outside of the group by, and just kept group_by(Item). That's pretty interesting.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, you could do it in `mutate`, then do the `group_by`, but i thought i would eliminate one step